# Структура скрипта для переноса данных между БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть старая(1) и новая(2) БД. Я переношу данные меджу двумя таблицами. Вопрос в том, как это сделать, если основная таблица тянет за собою по FK другие таблицы из(1).
Сейчас у меня есть один `SELECT` для таблицы в БД(1), и я делаю `INSERT`'ы в  таблицы из БД(2). Для переноса данных из других(*) таблиц нужно делать еще один `SELECT`?
Сейчас структура скрипта такая:

```
//подключение к (1)
SELECT из таблицы БД(1)
//подключение к (2)
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {... $data=$row['data']; ...}
INSERT в таблицы БД(2)
```

Нужно сделать еще один `SELECT` для связанных таблиц из (1) и впихнуть данные в тот же `$result`?

Comment: Проще всего будет сохранить существующие значения ключей. Если в каком-то месте новая БД этого не позволяет, то это надо решать отдельно для каждого такого места.

Comment: В тот же result не нужно, просто копируете таблицы по очереди, начиная от самой "главной" которая сама ни на кого не ссылается и потом все подчиненные.

Comment: В вопросе пропущен самый, пожалуй, важный факт - пусты ли таблицы-приёмники или нет. Если пусты - достаточно выстроить правильный порядок переноса данных, т.е. данные таблицы переносятся только тогда, когда перенесены данные всех таблиц, на которые она ссылается (альтернатива - отключить проверку ссылочной целостности перед переносом и включить по завершении). Если же в целевых таблицах имеются данные - задача становиться нетривиальной, особенно если в данных присутствуют дубликаты.

Comment: И - миграцию данных гораздо разумнее делать средствами сервера, а не гонять данные через клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае необходимо переносить последовательно все нужные вам таблицы. Т.е. данные впихивать в тот же result не нужно.

У вас получится примерно так:

```
//подключение к (1)
SELECT из таблицы1 БД(1)
//подключение к (2)
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {... $data=$row['data']; ...}
INSERT в таблицу1 БД(2)

//подключение к (1)
SELECT из таблицы2 БД(1)
//подключение к (2)
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {... $data=$row['data']; ...}
INSERT в таблицу2 БД(2)
```

Ну и так далее по всем необходимым таблицам.

Возможно проще организовать прямой перенос из одной БД в другую, примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO db2.table1 (column1, column2, ...) 
SELECT column1, column 2, ... FROM db1.table1
```

Для этого достаточно чтобы обе базы находились на одном сервере и был пользователь, который имел доступ к обеим базам данных.

Если же структура баз данных не меняется, возможно проще и правильнее будет сделать dump одной базы данных и развернуть его на другом сервере (в другой БД). Для этого есть множество различных инструментов, могу посоветовать PHPMyAdmin и HeidiSQL